# Autocomplete causes jQuery hover to fade out (Demo included)

Tags: jquery, html, hover, fadeout, autosuggest

Demo: http://www.christianbullock.com/so-demo/ (I know it's a bit rusty).

Screenshot: http://i46.tinypic.com/2rh7fgn.png

Hover over the blue rectangle to reveal the login panel. It works exactly how I'd like it to, with the exception that if you double-click one of the input forms to reveal the previously-entered usernames, by hovering over one of the suggested usernames the panel fades away...jQuery thinks my mouse has left the div when it actually hasn't.

Has anyone encountered anything like this before? Anyone know a fix?

Thanks.

Comment: Include the html and js code so we can locate the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the "autocomplete" plugin is going to add a `<div>` to hold the completion strings, and I'm pretty sure it adds that div to the end of the `<body>` content. Thus, when you mouse into that `<div>` you really are mousing out of your own form.

You could maybe have your handler explicitly treat the autocomplete `<div>` as being part of yours, or else you might be able to "move" the `<div>` the plugin adds into your own.

*edit* — if your problem stems from the *native* browser "autocomplete" dropdown (which you may want to disable for a login form anyway, if you can; try adding an "autocomplete" attribute and set it to "false"), then here's a possibility: in the event handler that fades your form container, you can check the current mouse position. If the mouse position is still within the bounding box of your form, then you can ignore the "mouseout".

Comment: Thanks for the answer, although the current method doesn't use an autocomplete "plugin", it's generated by the browser. If possible I'd like to avoid another plugin as I'm trying to avoid bloating it.

@thisMayhem: Edited above.

Comment: Oh oh I see - well it still may be more or less the same problem. I'll update my answer too.

Comment: Think I'm just going to disable autocomplete. 

Thanks:)

Comment: OK - I think the "autocomplete" attribute may actually need to be set to "off" instead of "false"; it's a weird little subject in its own right!